# ListBox not populating with BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a Winforms app. Listbox lstEncrypted not populating, no error. ProcessText.Statistics works just fine, encrypted gets the List of Objects, already checked in debugger. I dont know what is wrong. Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!!

```
public partial class FormUI : Form
{

    List<CharItem> encrypted = new List<CharItem>();
    BindingSource encryptedBinding = new BindingSource();


    public FormUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        encryptedBinding.DataSource = encrypted;
        lstEncrypt.DataSource = encryptedBinding;
        lstEncrypt.DisplayMember = "Display";
        lstEncrypt.ValueMember = "Display";
    }

    private void BtnStatisticsEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        encrypted = ProcessText.Statistics(txtBoxEncrypt.Text);

        encryptedBinding.ResetBindings(false);

    }
```

_

```
   public class CharItem
{
    public char Char { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public decimal Avg { get; set; }
    public string Display
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format($"{Char}    ({Position})    {Avg}%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `List<T>` doesn't tell the DataSource items have been added.  A `BindingList<T>` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

`CharItem` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the property changed event on property setters.  Something like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)  
{  
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then when a property changes simply call `NotifyPropertyChanged()` in the setter:

```
private string someData;
public string SomeData
{
    get { return someData; }
    set { someData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

You can notify the change of related properties (like `Display` in your example) by specifying the property name from any setter:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Display));
```

Without this any property sets don't get noticed by the `BindingSource`, which can't notify any bound control(s) to update.

Comment: The BindingList doesn't notify property changes either. There's no alternative to implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or a direct surrogate).

Comment: @Jimi It implements `IRaiseItemChangedEvents`.  Not quite the same as `INotifyPropertyChanged` I agree, but still workable.

Comment: The Item is a List item. Not a property of a class in the List.

Comment: @Jimi I'm not following.  Maybe a code example?  Adding, removing, clearing, etc... a `BindingList<T>` will raise events.  I do agree it will _not_ propagate changes to properties.  That's what `INotifyPropertyChanged` is for.  In short a `BindingList<T>` is useful if you care when the _collection_ changes, not the properties of an item inside the collection.

Comment: That's what I wrote in the first comment. The BindingList notifies changes of its content (the Items you add to the List). Changes to properties of the Items themselves are not notified. This is something the class object needs to do. Btw, when you add a `List<T>` to a BindingSource, the BindingSource creates a BindingList on its own. I.e., the BL generates ListChange events. Changing a property of an internal Item doesn't change the List.

Comment: @Jimi Ah, gotcha.  I didn't see anything in the question that referred specifically to properties inside a collection. In fact the question is made more confusing with this manual call to `encryptedBinding.ResetBindings(false);`, which kinda defeats the point of data binding.  I only mentioned `BindingList<T>` for scenarios where you can't change a classes implementation.  I can remove that from the answer if it's just confusing.

Comment: In relation to the question, it could be that the OP is generating a new BindingList, here: `encrypted = ProcessText.Statistics(txtBoxEncrypt.Text);`. If this method returns a new BindingList, there will be no ListChanged notifications (BindingList or no BindingList), of course.

Comment: @Jimi and Zero Thaknks for the suggestions! Sorry if my question is confusing, just learning here. Maybe you can explain me this: why if instead of          
      encrypted = ProcessText.Statistics(txtBoxEncrypt.Text); which returns a List<Charitems> i use for example      CharItem c = new CharItem; Encrypted.Add(c); the code works and lstEncrpted shows me the Display of c?

Comment: @zocacola That would fix the bug, yes.  You have a `BindingSource` that is attached to a specific _instance_ of a class (in this case `List<T>`).  You really shouldn't need to ever change the instance it points to.  That said, your solution works presuming that each item is _immutable_ and populated _prior_ to adding to the collection.  If the item is mutable and you want changes reflected on the GUI you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as mentioned.

Comment: @Zer0So lets say i use INotifyPropertyChanged, will that work for notifying that the List <CharItems> has changed? meaning adding or removing or sorting items in it? how should i do that?